# How exactly is object removed from memory in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I've read a bunch of articles about the memory management in swift. However, there is still some things which are not clear.

1. What does it mean to free memory?
2. Is memory freed exactly after counter for strong references is zero or is there some event which triggers deinit?
3. How does swift knows that some piece of memory is occupied?

Seems like this is more about OS rather than language but still I would appreciate any answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clarify, when we talk about "Swift *the language*", it's just talking about the language syntax and semantics in the abstract, without any regards for a concrete implementation. *Technically*, the Swift programming language can be implemented with multiple different memory-management strategies, including conventional Garbage Collection, although some APIs (`isKnownUniquelyReferenced(_:)` and the CoW behaviours that depend on it) strongly imply that reference-counting is used.

So everything from here on will be talking about the [main Swift implementation by Apple](https://github.com/Apple/swift), and not others (like [RemObjects Silver](https://www.remobjects.com/elements/silver/))

1. > What does it mean to free memory?

   It means that a function like [`free()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) is called, which takes a pointer to the allocated memory and marks it as "available". Future allocations (such as with [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc)) are free to vend out this memory next time a new allocation is needed.
2. > Is memory freed exactly after counter for strong references is zero or is there some event which triggers deinit?

   Swift's ARC decrements reference counts by calling `swift_release(the_object)`. If the decrement causes the reference count to hit 0 or less, then it immediately triggers the `deinit` and deallocation code path.

   Unlike a garbage collector (which can defer object deallocation indefinitely), this happens deterministically, right at the point of last use of the object.

   You can see this for yourself: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2db4a038c3ecbbc5a9b4d90c36b684e2f56b022f/stdlib/public/SwiftShims/swift/shims/RefCount.h#L1028-L1030
3. > How does Swift knows that some piece of memory is occupied?

   It doesn't, really. Most automatic memory management schemes take a very conservative definition of "garbage": An object is garbage if and only if there are no more strong references to it. In essence, if we know there's no more strong references to an object, we can be *certain* that the user doesn't need it anymore (because they couldn't possible access it, even if they wanted).

   If they didn't take such a conservative stance, any false positive would mean the deallocation of an object that's still in use, which would be catastrophic.

   So as far as the system is concerned, any object with a non-zero reference count is "in use"/"occupied"/"not garbage," until its reference count eventually reaches 0.

Comment: This is exactly that I wanted to know. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Happy to help! Got any other follow-up questions?

Comment: I reread it carefully and everything seems clear :)

Comment: Just to confuse things ever-so-slightly, it is worth knowing that Swift objects can participate in an autorelease pool. This is less common for Swift objects, but still legal in many common cases. This can delay their deallocation until the next pool drain. (This doesn't conflict with Alexander's claim that when the reference count is 0, it's immediately deallocated, but it can confuse your intuition about when the reference count hits zero.) For most (though not all...) the gory gory details, see https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html